# Netbeans Restful WebService

Tags: json, web-services, rest, netbeans

I'm trying to make a simple Restful WebService from Database using Netbeans. Everything went good.  I followed a Netbeans tutorial which can be found [here.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

But when i try to get the json result i found out that the int values(for exemple the id) is considered as String:

```
{"task":[
        {"id":"1","label":"get dressed"},
        {"id":"2","label":"make breakfast"}
        ]}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that NetBeans Restful WS only returns JSON that contains strings? You will have to cast those values to the correct type.

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for, but you can do the casting on the client's side: With JavaScript, Java, or any language that processes the JSON results.

Comment: well i would like to avoid to do the casting on the client's side because if i'm working with a big amount of data it will be painful to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737597/how-to-return-a-long-property-as-json-string-value-with-jaxb). It is the opposite of your requirement but the same solution should work for you. The `@XmlSchemaType` annotation should help.

I assume that in your `@XmlRootElement` class the attribute type is `int`.